# How to redraw heat map using Leaflet.heat?

Tags: leaflet, heatmap

I've done the heat map using this code

```
var heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints, {radius: 25},{gradient: {1: 'blue', 0.65: 'lime', 1: 'red'}}).addTo(map);
```

but now I've have to redraw the map with new set of data, How to do it?
Any syntax or code snippets is there please share here.

I've tried to use `redraw()` method but its not working for me so how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
heat.remove();
```

or

```
heat.redraw().remove();
```